# APP start error from android 6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

What's wrong with the code, I do not know how?
code no error, but APP start error from android 6.

Please help me.

```
 long enqueue;
    DownloadManager dm;

    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse("http://grupovrt.ddns.net:81/v4.2.apk"));


    String updatePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Updates" + File.separator + "v4.2.apk";
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(updatePath)));
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/updates", "v4.2.apk");


    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Descarc noi actualizari!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If I delete this line go

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/updates", "v4.2.apk");
```

Comment: I found error.
In android 6 does not get automatic access to storage space and gives error.
How do I request to permit them in android m?

Comment: @Please check the link in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your targetSDK is 23, you always need to check the permissions.**

Here is a great tutorial of checking and request permission on Android 6.0
[New Android runtime permission](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Answer (score 3):

```
int permissionCheckStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                                  Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (permissionCheckStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
   requestPermissions(new String[{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE);
}else{
 //add your code here
}
```

MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE is any integer.
Please refer : http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

OR

The user can enable access to storage space by enabling app permission to storage.

Settings > Apps > (Click on settings icon right top to navigate to "Configure App") > App Permissions > Storage > "Enable the permission for your app"

Hope this helps.